# Cant find my class with testing Unit Test Generator

Tags: c#, testing

I know how to write simple unit tests. My problem is that I can't find my class in the unit test project. I have imported the referens to the other project that I want to test.

I can't do Generate unit test when I right click and I can't even create an object on the class connection.cs that's in the project that I have used referens to.

I have the addon (Unit Test Generator) and I can do it on some methods in the usercontrol class but that class uses my connection.cs that I want to do testing on.

Anyone have any idea whats the problem

[image: Unit Test Picture]

Comment: class is public ?

Comment: Is your class public ?

Comment: I'm guessing ... That you'r `Connection.cs` file contains `internal` or `private` class `Connection` which is not visible outside it's `Assembly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st**

Make sure your class is `Public`

**2nd**

If you have a `constructor`. Declaring the constructor `public` can fix this problem

Though the `constructors` have no `name` only a `type`

Comment: Afnan Ahmad Im so glad you helped me it was just as you said. I had forgot to make it public and there was no public empty constructor